# Android studio Debugger Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-studio

I'm having a hard time here... Sometime ago, my Android studio debugger stoped from work... I get this error message whenever I launch an application:

> Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.

I know that there is a lot related to that problem here, but everyone seems to get this error when using Eclipse, and I'm using Android studio, as said before...

Comment: Did you try closing "adb.exe"

Comment: Yes ... I tried to kill the process then start android studio, and I tried to restart adb via cmd

Comment: I have the same problem.  Android Studio, not Eclipse.

Comment: Have you solved it ?

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem when I start the ddms by enter monitor from the terminal. And I try to start it by selecting Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Open terminal window in android studio run two commands:

   i)adb kill-server

   ii)adb start-server, then do following steps
2. file->setting->Debugger
3. In Debugger window check section Built in-server(last section)
4. change port number:63341 or 63343

Comment: It doesn't work. I change it from 63342 to 63343 and nothing different.

Comment: If not work, disconnect your phone and restart android studio.